# Выпуск видеочата №5 с @Juan M 19.10.2017 в 18:12. Присоединяйтесь!

Tags: обсуждение, видеочат

С радостью спешу пригласить всех участников сообщества присоединиться к видеочату 19 октября 2017 года в 18:12 по московскому времени. Гостем второго выпуска будет мой коллега, [@Juan M](https://stackexchange.com/users/6254215/juan-m). Хуан — знаток развития сообществ. До того как присоединиться к нашей команде, он более десяти лет занимался управлением сообществ по всем мыслимым и немыслимым тематикам. Что интересно, в определенные моменты, ему приходилось работать с более чем сотней сообществ одновременно! Сейчас он помогает сразу трем международным сайтам: Stack Overflow на испанском, японском и португальском.

Если вы когда-либо задумывались о том, чтобы заняться созданием и поддержкой сообщества — самое время подготовить и задать ваши вопросы нашему гостю!

Видео будет доступно в реальном времени на канале сообщества: http://youtu.be/iU8-Q6ADPOY.

#### Пожалуйста, задавайте ваши вопросы гостю!

Как и ранее, главная цель видеочата – узнать друг друга поближе. Расскажите, гостям о том, что вам интересно в них! Пожалуйста, задавайте ваши вопросы участнику выпуска!

Ваши вопросы участникам выпуска вы можете задать в [чате сообщества](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--). Обязательно, задавая вопрос, упомяните `@NicolasChabanovsky` и/или имя участника, кому вопрос адресован , чтобы я (мы) мог своевременно отреагировать на ваш вопрос. Также вы можете отправить ваш вопрос к участникам заранее мне на почту (nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com) или опубликовать в комментарием или ответов в данном вопросе.

С нетерпением ждем вас!

Comment: В в 18: **12** ? Он по пятницам на час раньше домой уходит что ли?

Comment: На каком языке трансляция будет?

Comment: @Андрей Не совсем понял ваш вопрос. Вообще, Хуан их Техаса. 18:12 по Москве – это 10:12 утра в Техасе.

Comment: @Андрей на английском.

Comment: [Вот тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6154/213987) целый ворох вопросов волнует участника, можете выбрать Хуану наиболее интересные.

Comment: @AK Спасибо! Вопросы действительно интересные и уже давно в моем списке!)

Comment: Приятно было послушать людей с реальным опытом поддерживания сообщества. Плохо что со слишком многим согласен :) Напомнило о видео: [Building an \[open-source\] community on purpose](https://youtu.be/aM_jAWV1LUs)