# Концепция модерации на портале: для чего это модераторам?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

На фоне очередных выборов модераторов сообщества навеяло <sup>холивар детектед</sup>.

---

Может кому-то это покажется странным, а кому-то вообще кощунством, но мне не даёт покоя такой вот вполне приземлённый и меркантильный диссонанс.

Всё, с одной стороны, просто и старо, как мир - пирамида Маслоу и прочее. Человек, как правило, отдаёт что-то и при этом желает что-то получить взамен. Денежку, благодарность, уважение и тп - список можно продолжать бесконечно и, разумеется, не всегда это материальные блага, но тем не менее - отдача.

А с другой стороны - все эти разговоры про "*постройку <s>коммунизма</s> коммьюнити*".

Насколько вероятно, что "*стройка светлого будущего*" - иллюзия? Как в "Матрице". А вдруг, зарабатывая на рекламе и компаниях-работодателях, этот портал очень хорошо экономит на содержании штата модераторов и прививает идеологию самоподдерживаемого сообщества в своих корыстных интересах? На мой взгляд, эти разговоры о некой "высокой идее" не лишены доли лицемерия. Есть в штате владельца SO персонал, работающий бесплатно? Но при этом все говорят о "великой цели", которую они преследуют. Я не против цели, но как-то чересчур слащаво и неправдоподобно.

---

**Внимание, вопросы:**

- Что есть "*коммьюнити*" и зачем его надо нам?
- Зачем (*за какие коврижки*) весь этот ацкий труд модераторам?

*<sub>Никого не хочу обидеть и заранее прошу прощения. Все совпадения случайны.</sub>*

Comment: Связано: [Зачем вы здесь?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305/181100)

Comment: @D-side это отдельный вопрос "Зачем вы здесь, модераторы?" )

Comment: Да, связано, но модерация - абсолютно другой уровень. Тем более вопросов 2

Comment: Но это спрашивали примерно на прошлых выборах: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2147/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-2015-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0

Comment: @Nofate и Nofate сказал "Хочу приносить счастье людям", попивая кофе из чашечки StackOverflow %)

Comment: Зачем это участникам и зачем это модераторам -- два очень крупных вопроса, а в тексте поста есть и более мелкие побочные вопросы.

Comment: Закралась в голову дурная мысль, что не все из тех, кто метят в модераторы понимают всю ответственность и объём работы, который ложиться на их плечи. Наверняка есть и те, кто считает это привилегией или "жизненной ачивкой". Таких всегда хватает. В целом, вопрос хороший. Порой стоит им задаваться ). Лично я считаю, что можно работать и за идею, если она тебе по душе. Наш мир процветает в основном за счёт энтузиастов, верных своему делу.

Comment: @EgorTrutnev - *Лично я считаю, что можно работать и за идею*, я тоже так считаю, но мои дети почему-то считают, что я должен их кормить :)

Comment: Комьюнити - это часть зоны комфорта. Чем она больше - тем, в целом, лучше человеку в ней. Есть те, кому хорошо у себя в квартире, а на подъезд чхать. Есть те, кому не комфортно, когда в подъезде насрано и он пытается(или нет) на это воздействовать. Дальше двор, город, страна, планета. Так же и с "виртуальным миром"

Comment: @Anatol, нууу.., они в этом не одиноки. Я тоже хочу, чтобы меня кормили, но энтузиастов пока (ага, надейся) нет. )

Comment: @rjhdby - *Есть те, кому не комфортно, когда в подъезде насрано и он пытается(или нет) на это воздействовать*, то есть человек руководствуется исключительно своим видением критериев комфорта и начинает наворачивать на весь подъезд, приговаривая: "Для вас же стараюсь"?

Comment: @Anatol в целом да. Но остальным же пофиг? А если не пофиг, то никто не мешает включиться в процесс ;)

Comment: @rjhdby - а если остальным комфортно именно так и они не хотят ничего менять, но из-за кого-то более инициативного вынуждены будут защищать свои интересы либо уступать (в силу разных причин, например - страха) и жить про правилам того самого, инициативного? То есть один человек, преследуя свой интерес, выводит из зоны комфорта более одного человека?

Comment: @Anatol то мы бы до сих пор сидели на пальмах

Comment: @rjhdby - *мы бы до сих пор сидели на пальмах* - неочевидно. Точно так же можно сказать "мы бы не получили столько войн и насилия", зависит от точки опоры

Comment: @Anatol с точки зрения сидящего на пальме может быть, но лично мне больше нравится сидеть за компом и вести философские диспуты, что стало возможным в том числе и после войн и насилия

Comment: @rjhdby - агрессивная и циничная позиция :)

Comment: @Anatol просто вы упустили основной посыл моего первого коммента, про зону комфорта. Для сидящего на пальме она ограничена самой пальмой, а для меня она несколько больше. В частности этот ресурс в нее входит и мне хочется, чтобы в ней было хорошо ;)

Answer (score 7):

Сначала приходишь на ресурс за ответами. Через некоторое время замечаешь, что и сам можешь их давать. Конкретно у меня это происходило на фоне некоторого раздражения, типа "Ну что же вы городите?! Смотрите как надо.", когда нет сил не вмешаться. Давая ответы и проводя на ресурсе больше времени, начинаешь замечать бардак. Конкретно я из тех людей, которые не могут не разложить карандаши на столе по длине и строго параллельно. Начинаешь наводить порядок. Сначала по мелочи, самые режущие глаз моменты. Потом всё больше, больше и больше. И вот ты уже модерируешь. Без платы, без какой-либо идеологической основы, без желания выпендриваться. Просто делаешь не особенно задумываясь, так же как гоняешь шпану из своего подъезда, чтобы куревом не воняло, наплёвано не было и стены не разрисовали. Подъезд вроде общий и где-то там есть управляющая компания, но он и твой тоже.

Answer (score 6):

Давайте я напишу об этом с точки зрения бывшего модератора.

1. Начиная с какого-то уровня репутации (где-то наверное 20-30 тыс.) вдруг замечаешь, что ресурс становится частью твоей жизни, то есть ты уже целенаправленно выделяешь время на ответы, просмотр комментариев и проч. В целом этом где-то 3-4 часа в неделю - вроде немного, но это 3-4 часа. Зная сколько стоит 1 твой час, за год набегает такая нормальная сумма (виртуально конечно)
2. В этом смысле модерация является естественным продолжением этого процесса - ты не можешь остановиться и берешь в руки инструмент модератора и бросаешься разгребать авгиевы конюшни и становишься ассенизатором (добровольно)
3. Через несколько месяцев ты замечаешь, что или ты тратишь на ресурс больше времени или у тебя падает скорость прироста репутации - чаще всего и то и другое и ты начинаешь тратить 2-3 часа в день
4. Потом во время очередного мегасрача в каментах или чате ты вдруг понимаешь, что [кто-то тебя нагло использует](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact) - что удовольствие от ресурса ты перестаешь получать
5. Потом ты вспоминаешь [зачем ты вообще сюда пришел](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315/5648) и понимаешь, что ты что-то не то делаешь
6. Все это в сумме приводит тебя [к предложению об оставке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1777/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0/1785#1785)

Выводы, каждый может делать для себя сам.

Comment: Рад что Вы выбрали красную пилюлю.

Answer (score 5):

Давайте начнём с простого и общего. Вопрос большой, поэтому всё сжато и в конспективной форме, если будет интересно — могу подробнее расписать.

С введением разделения труда человечество резко улучшило уровень жизни каждого отдельного индивида. Люди и до этого были социальными животными, но именно с разделением труда выросла значимость социальной составляющей.  Люди могут стать богаче только если они будут приносить пользу социуму — такую, за которую социум будет согласен платить.

Человек, который придумал stackoverflow — придумал очень полезную для ИТ-сообщества вещь, внакладе не останется. Используя so каждый из нас может увеличить свои знания, увеличить производительность своего труда. В эпоху цифровой экономики это является крупным преимуществом перед другими работниками.

> Сообщество
>   ([клуб](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1)) —
>   это группа людей, объединённых общими целями.

Цель я писал выше: увеличить личный объём знаний и производительность труда. Люди объединяются в клубы, чтобы сократить собственные издержки на достижение целей.

Если вы вспомните, как провели несколько часов, а то и дней над сложным вопросом и как быстро можно узнать готовый ответ из базы давно отвеченных вопросов на so — я думаю, вы согласитесь, что so оказывает значительную помощь в ускоренном накоплении знаний.

Объяснение даю на пальцах (более подробно см. раздел "трансакционные издержки"), если будет интересно — можете подробнее почитать про экономику клубных правил и институциональную экономику, область весьма интересная.

Хорошие научно-популярные работы можно найти у [Долгина](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), [Аузана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD,_%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80_%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), можете начать например с этих вводных материалов:

- [Институциональная экономика для чайников](https://esquire.ru/auzan-1)
- [Как нам стать договоропригодными, или Практическое руководство по коллективным действиям. Начала экономической теории клубов](http://adolgin.ru/online/)

Запомнили, что коммьюнити — это вещь, резко снижающая издержки? Формально я уже ответил на ваш вопрос. У вас могут возникнуть дальнейшие вопросы о том, что не все эти издержки платят — тут читайте мат. часть по решению проблемы "безбилетников", есть отдельно [работы по соотношению альтруизма/эгоизма](http://polit.ru/article/2010/06/18/markov/) и т.п.

Я хочу остановиться на более неявном вопросе, он кажется не звучал: почему so был построен на принципах 'be nice'. Нет, не для того, чтобы зажать лишнюю модераторскую копейку в кубышку основателя.

Представьте, что у вас есть два клуба, таких как stackoverflow, в какой вы будете ходить: там где отвечают только на вопросы по технологии1 (скажем, c#) или в котором отвечают на сто технологий? Ответ очевиден. So старается расшириться и стать самым крупным сообществом среди других, чтобы вовлечь как можно больше участников. Ему с этого прямая прибыль: больше участников — меньше издержки каждого конкретного участника. Честно-честно. Вот что удобнее: три модератора как рабы на галерах привязаны к очереди проверок или пять модераторов по полчаса в день?

И понимаете, какая штука... Чтобы построить действительно крупное сообщество — нужны позитивные гуманистические ценности. Вроде мелочь, но именно от этого зависит предельный размер сообщества.

И последнее о чём я хотел бы сказать — это о том, что у вас лично какое-то подозрение к подобным ценностям. Слишком слащавые, где-то меня хотят надуть... Мне кажется, что в значительной мере это сказываются десятилетия проводимой государством политики в нашем государстве, когда выхолащивалась гражданская инициатива, а людей всячески разобщали. Просто токсичная атмосфера, доставшаяся нам в наследство.

Ещё я мог бы поставить звёздочки в паре мест выше по тексту, где я немного упростил материал и там правильнее было бы более подробно ответить, но пост и так вышел достаточно большой (тема сама большая), так что мне кажется, что я просто не угадаю, где будут уточняющие вопросы. Оставлю как есть.

Comment: @Anatol В ответ принципиально не стал вписывать часть, посвящённую ответу на вопрос 'зачем это модераторам': каждый ответил на эту часть вопроса, можете [почитать сами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6051/213987) и решить, кто более достоин представлять интересы сообщества в целом.

Comment: *Запомнили, что коммьюнити — это вещь, резко снижающая издержки?* это справедливо для рядового пользователя, задающего вопросы/ищущего готовые ответы. Модераторы же, как правило, люди с богатейшим опытом и знаниями, которые априори не нуждаются в коммьюнити с целью снижения своих издержек. Как раз наоборот, они свои издержки увеличивают, тратя время на модерацию. Нет?

Comment: В целом ответ мне понравился, спасибо, поразмышляю ещё

Comment: "увеличить личный объём знаний и производительность труда" -- это у кого как сложится. Да, здесь интересно. Но, пожалуй, производительность-то как раз падает из-за кучи времени, потраченного на развлечение.